# Why my cost function is so high?

Tags: linear-regression, gradient-descent, implementation

I am trying to implement the gradient descent algorithm from scratch and use it on the Boston dataset. Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


dataset = load_boston()
X = boston['LSTAT']
y = boston['MEDV']

def linearRegression2(b0 = 0, b1 = 1, lr = 0.00001, n_times = 1000):
partial_B0 = partial_B1 = 0
errors = []
m = len(y)
i = 0
for i in range(n_times):
    error = y - (b0 + X * b1)
    #Updating b0 and b1
    partial_B0 += -lr * (error.sum() / m) 
    partial_B1 += -lr * (X.T.dot(error) / m)
    b0 = b0 - (lr * partial_B0)
    b1 = b1 - (lr * partial_B1)
    errors.append(mean_squared_error(y, (b0 + X * b1)))
    i += 1

print(b0, b1)
print('Iteration i', i)
return errors


error = linearRegression2()
plt.plot(np.arange(1, 1000+1), error)
plt.ylabel('Error')
```

**However, when I plot my cost function, it is decreasing but still too high. I tried to decrease the learning rate, increase the iteration but not changing much.**

[image]

Comment: If you want to decrease the loss faster you should increase the learning rate instead of decreasing it.

Comment: I tried that one too. Still not decreasing much.

Comment: One mistake I see is the fact that you are using the learning rate twice, one when calculating the partial derivatives and once when updating `b0` and `b1`. The learning rate should only be used when updating `b0` and `b1` and is not used in calculating the partial derivates to `b0` and `b1`.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One mistake I see is the fact that you are using the learning rate twice, one when calculating the partial derivatives and once when updating `b0` and `b1`. The learning rate should only be used when updating `b0` and `b1` and is not used in calculating the partial derivates to `b0` and `b1`.